# Element on IOS Programming

Tags: iphone, element

Im kinda new to Stack Overflow so bear with me please. I am trying to design an iPhone app and I noticed a feature on Huffington Post app that I have been trying to replicate with a different style. I am confused on whether they are loading this as a html inside a webview, or if they are reproducing this programmatically on XCode.

I have looked at UI Picker and UI PopOverController and neither can replicate into that. Can someone give me some advise on what element I have to use in XCode?

Here are some attached screenshots

Comment: You cannot post inline images until your reputation is higher.  Edit your question and put in the URLs of the images instead.

Comment: Just wanna point out that you cannot use UIPopoverController if you develop an iPhone app. It is only available to iPad.

Comment: @Raymond Wang - Good comment.  I have seen apps emulate popovers on the iPhone, but it is essentially creation of your own partial view and action code for when one taps on an area not within that custom partial view.

Comment: yeah sorry guys here is the link

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/404/photo1n.png/

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: here is the screen shot

what i am confused on is how the table is generated or what element of iphone is used

Thanks once again!

Comment: @trumpetlicks - Exactly. It's certainly possible to do popover on iphone if using work around. I just wanna say that UIPopoverController is definitely not something need to be considered.

Comment: It is most likely a UIPopoverController with a UITableView inside it.

Comment: They are probably using some custom implementation of UIPopOverController that works on iphones and ipods (since the default is ipad only). [Here is the most popular one](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

Comment: Right, but it isnt going to be the standard apple UIPopOverController if on an iPhone :-)

Comment: @vcv123, if you google how to do popover on iPhone, I bet you can find some APIs or tutorials to do it.

Comment: You'll find loads of popover-style variants here: http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=popover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what your screen shot looks like, here is my guess of what they did:

On the view which they bring up the "popover", they have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell. At the right end of the UITableViewCell(the image with plus sign) is a button, and based on the position of the button, they can decide the position of the popover and direction of the arrow.

They used a custom popover control. Inside the popover, there is a UITableView take all the space.

If you wanna do the same thing, you will have to know

1. How to use custom UITableViewCell.
2. How to do popover on iPhone.
3. Delegation if you wanna the view underneath to react to what you click inside your popover.

I can provide more details if you need.

Comment: Thank You Raymond but I definitely think I figured it out!